# Hibernate selects nothing

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, character-encoding

I have MySQL InnoDB table utf-8 encoded. This table has only id and name field. Names are in russian language and 1 name in English for testing purpose. English name selects ok but when trying to select with russian name it returns empty list. I tried to build queries both with Criterion and HQL.

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from FirstName where name='free' ");
getHibernateTemplate().find("from FirstName where name='ИННА' ");
```

Here is connection string - 
`?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8`

i'm using hibernate 3.2.7.ga and spring 2.5.6.SEC03

Here is hibernate log:

```
Hibernate: /* from FirstName where name='ИННА'  */ select firstname0_.`id` as id1_24_, firstname0_.`name` as name2_24_ from `first_name` firstname0_ where firstname0_.`name`='ИННА' limit ?
```

Comment: Have you tested without the characterEncoding parameter?

Comment: Yes, but it issue still appears.

Comment: Have you tried it manually in mysql to see if the database returns anything?

Comment: Sql "SELECT * FROM first_name where name='ИННА';" in mysql command tool returns empty set...
but in MySQL Query Browser returns 2 entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all, i have found an answer.

The problem was in connection string.
I did refactor and moved connection string to the properties file instead of xml with spring-bean. But i did not changed "`&amp;`" entity to the "&".
Successfull connection string is in properties file

```
jdbc:mysql://${host}:${port}/${database}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
```

XML file changes `&amp;` entities to the correct, but properties format don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria coCriteria = Session.createCriteria(coClass).add(Restrictions.eq(strColumnName, strColumnValue));
list = coCriteria.list();
```

Did you try with this hibernate criteria.
Where "Session" will the session object of hibernate generated session.
1)coClass = "pojo class name" 
2)strColumnName = "pojo class field name" in your case it will be "name" i guess 
3)strColumnValue = in your case it will be "ИННА"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the character encoding at database level? 
According to MySQL documentation, Cyrillic characters are supported with "cp1251"

You may take a look at [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-cyrillic-sets.html) as well

Comment: Yes, database tables and field are in UTF-8 encoding and utf8_ci collation.

Comment: Did you try defining your query using : session.createSQLQuery(...)? As this would let you work with "native query", you should at least be able to pinpoint where the problem actually is: on DB side or on how Hibernate generates the underlying query